# Comparision for D3.js vs zingChart library for visualizations and charting

Tags: d3.js, charts, javascript, zingchart

I am looking for visualization and charting in my project.

So Suggest all possible comparison for `d3.js and zingChart`

Please also consider following factors :

```
1.Layout adjustments on webpage
2.Learning simplicity
3.Documentatin available
4.Ease of Implementation
5.flash support
```

Finally I would like to know which is the best choice from these two libraries?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: "Suggest all possible comparison for d3.js and zingChart" I think you're asking a bit much here.

Comment: Then tell the differences which you know..Thanx in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**D3 :**

1. Open source - YES(BSD license)
2. Focuses on - D3 is drawing library which focuses on charting + data visualization
3. Mobile friendly - No [Please See Detail](http://softwareprocess.es/a/canvas-talk.pdf)
4. Graphics Technology - SVG / HTML5 / CSS
5. Compatibility - IE 6.0 + all modern browsers
6. Export Chart Data - Needs more coding at server side to export charts
7. Popularity - Widely used and popular
8. 3D Support - No
9. Online Support / help - Full Support with good documentation and examples as it is open source
10. Offline limitations - No

**Zingchart :**

1. Open source -No **(but free trial of full version available)**.
   Price : $249 to $9999 (Trial version available with watermark )
2. Focuses on - <strike>Pure Charting library, custom data visualization is difficult</strike> **100's of predefined chart types, geographical maps, custom data visualization modules... all with tons of styling options**
3. Mobile friendly - Yes
4. Graphics Technology - HTML5/Canvas/SVG/VML/Flash/Image/**PDF. with server-side charting options available**
5. Compatibility - IE **(7&8)** 9 + all modern browsers
6. Export Chart Data - Easy to export generated charts in various formats - (pdf,png,bmp,**SVG**)
7. Popularity - <strike>Not much</strike> **Used by the Fortune 100 to startups -- large implementations for NASDAQ, Adobe, Alcatel-Lucent (just to name a few)**
8. 3D Support - Yes
9. Online Support / help - <strike>Average Documentations and examples</strike> **Getting started guides, documentation by chart type, features, and API methods/events, full JSON Attributes/Syntax, Tutorials
   Access to personalized support via email, and phone, right-click to share your charts for questions**
10. Offline limitations - No

Comment: Notice I highlighted the differences with the OP's answer. The original post was difficult to understand. Merrily, put more effort the next time please.

Answer (score 2):

D3 :

1. Open source - YES(BSD license)
2. Focuses on - D3 is drawing library which focuses on charting + data visualization
3. Mobile friendly - No [Please See Detail](http://softwareprocess.es/a/canvas-talk.pdf)
4. Graphics Technology - SVG / HTML5 / CSS
5. Compatibility - IE 6.0 + all modern browsers
6. Export Chart Data - Needs more coding at server side to export charts
7. Popularity - Widely used and popular
8. 3D Support - No
9. Online Support / help - Full Support  with good documentation and examples  as it is open source
10. Offline limitations - No

Zingchart :

1. Open source -No Price : $249  to $9999 
   (Trial version available with watermark )
2. Focuses on - Pure Charting library, custom data visualization is difficult
3. Mobile friendly - Yes
4. Graphics Technology - HTML5/Canvas/SVG/VML/Flash/Image
5. Compatibility - IE 9 + all modern browsers
6. Export Chart Data - Easy to export generated Charts in various formats(pdf,png,bmp)
7. Popularity - Not much
8. 3D Support - Yes
9. Online Support / help - Average Documentations and examples
10. Offline limitations - No

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to get the details on JavaScript based charting library. While searching for this, I came across this wiki page. [Comparison Of JavaScript Charting Frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks). I hope this helps.